# forward a forwarded mail with postfix, based on rules

Tags: postfix, forwarding

How can I get postfix to forward an incoming email to one or more different local alias(es), if the address I want the rule to be based on, is not the recipient? The address I want to act on is from a forwarded mail.

It goes like this:
**On external account:**

- voicemail addressed to `123+voicemail@externaldomain` gets delivered to the main
  `myname@externaldomain` account. (this combines normal text mail and mail with voice attachments)
- All mail is forwared to my server using `tonline@mydomain`

**On local postfix server:**

- Now I want to forward only voice mail originally addressed to `123+voicemail@externaldomain` to my aliases for `voice@mydomain` and `voice@myotherdomain`
  That's why I can't simply use bcc_maps
- In `virtual_alias_maps` I tried:

  - Using `virtual_alias_maps` I'm able to redirect
    `voice@mydomain to myvoice@mydomain, myvoice@myotherdomain`
    but this includes regular mail, too.
  - So I tried a rule like
    `123+voice@externaldomain voice@mydomain, voice@myotherdomain`
    but this doesn't trigger.

example mail when finally received by me using the rule from my first attempt:

```
Return-Path: <123@externaldomain>
X-Original-To: voice@mydomain
Delivered-To: myvoice@mydomain    
From: 456 <456@externaldomain>
To: 123+voice@externaldomain
Subject: Call from 456
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using a sieve message filter like this:

```
require ["copy","fileinto","imap4flags"];
# rule:[VoiceMailForwarder]
if anyof (header :contains "to" "+Sprachbox@t-online.de", header 
:contains "to" "fritzbox@example.com")
{
    redirect :copy "voicemail@example.com";
}
```

using roundcube with the managesieve plugin makes this easy. There is an addon for thunderbird, too

Answer (score 0):

Since your decision is totally dependant on `To` header, you can add `header_checks`

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
# ...
# ...
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header.re
# ...

#/etc/postfix/header.re
/^To:(.*)123+voice@externaldomain/        REDIRECT  whoever@whateverdomain.tld
```

Comment: This works fine to distinguish voice mail from text mail. It seems that `virtual` is not executed anymore when a Redirect was in action?  With `virtual` I'd be able to spread the mail to multiple users.